# Error "network provider does not exist, accuracy=3" when requesting provider

Tags: android, gps, location

I search for the best Provider using this code:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(false);

return locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

Obviously, I have necessary permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

However, it gives me an error

```
network provider does not exist, accuracy=3
```

The strange thing is that if I use

```
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);//FINE, not HIGH
```

it works just ok. What could be the reason? How can I use the HIGH value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Criteria.setAccuracy:

```
/**
 * Indicates the desired accuracy for latitude and longitude. Accuracy
 * may be {@link #ACCURACY_FINE} if desired location
 * is fine, else it can be {@link #ACCURACY_COARSE}.
 * More accurate location may consume more power and may take longer.
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if accuracy is not one of the supported constants
 */
public void setAccuracy(int accuracy) {
    if (accuracy < NO_REQUIREMENT || accuracy > ACCURACY_COARSE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("accuracy=" + accuracy);
    }
    if (accuracy == ACCURACY_FINE) {
        mHorizontalAccuracy = ACCURACY_HIGH;
    } else {
        mHorizontalAccuracy = ACCURACY_LOW;
    }
}
```

setAccuracy(ACCURACY_FINE) will assign the mHorizontalAccuracy to ACCURACY_HIGH